# Alfresco community5.1.x /Company Home/Data Dictionary/Scripts/triggerStartworkflow.js how can execute from clients javascript is this possible?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

Alfresco community5.1.x,i have create js file placed in path of `/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Scripts/triggerStartworkflow.js` how can execute from clients javascript is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to execute it on the server tier ?

Comment: yes i can execute client javascript from server side javascript

Answer (score 1):

On way to execute ServerSide - JS is to use **JavaScript console** !

You can find more info about this addon here: https://github.com/share-extras/js-console

Comment: Yes , Installed javascript console in my alfresco how can use this javascript console and how can i call server side javascript from client side javascript please help me with reference

Comment: You can find instruction in here: https://github.com/share-extras/js-console#using-the-component or check out the video here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3JIeVY8Nnk

Answer (score 0):

you may have to apply rules on folder to execute this script file.

or you can call a repo webscript in that you have to include this js file to your repo webscript. and you can execute it.